# Get a percentage of the page you're currently downloading using Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Is it possible to get the current percentage from the download page?

For example, to determine the number of elements on a page at the beginning of a download

Then in `page.on('request')` I would compare the total number of elements with processed.

Is it possible to do it or is it crap?

Comment: You can get page.metrics() from here https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagemetrics
But it will provide the time consumed and all.

Comment: Thank you but that's not what I need

Comment: Do you mean you're trying to download some images?

Comment: No, one web page. I need to get html with download progress